# Zumero server with HTTPS: are wildcard certificates valid?

Tags: iis, zumero

We are migrating our Zumero service in order to use HTTPS. In the server [installation doc](http://zumero.com/docs/zumero_for_sql_server_install.html#enabling-ssl), it says that an SSL certificate for the fully qualified domain name (FQDN) is required.

My question is: Can we use a wildcard certificate instead of an FQDN certificate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's between you and IIS. If the certificate works to secure a web page on the same domain, without browser warnings, it will work for Zumero as well. Zumero operates within IIS's encryption.